# How can i add note, caution, warning quote inside the text?

Tags: css, html

I use wordpress theme in my website. Question is simple, i want to add inside my articles as an inline note, caution, warning quote like picture. How can i do that? Is there any plugin or way to do that?

[image]

Comment: You can create an HTML structure for quote using `<blockquote>` tag and style it using CSS as desired. No need for a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter and add your note after every post. Then you can style it to have a nice quote.

```
add_filter('the_content','add_my_note');
function add_my_note($content){
    // Write your note here
    $note = '
        <div class="my-note">
            <h3>Note Header</h3>
            <p>Note body</p>
        </div>';
    // Append the note to the content
    $content = $content . $note;
    // Return the modified content
    return $content;
}
```

This will add the note to your post's content. Now time to style it.

```
.my-note {
    display:block;
    background:lightgray;
    border-width: 0 0 0 3px;
    border-color:grey;
    color:black;
    border-style:solid;
    padding: 1em;
}
.my-note h3 {
    display:block;
    font-size: 2em
}
.my-note p {
    display:block;
    font-size : 1em;
}
```

I've done some basic styling for you, which you can change to fit your tastes,

Answer (score 0):

Run in your theme the CSS of admin dashboard.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-admin' );
```

Then you could use [WordPress admin alerts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices) CSS

Example from docs:

```
<div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
    <p><?php _e( 'Done!', 'sample-text-domain' ); ?></p>
</div>
```

Another option could be done if you will have a [bootstrap based theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/search/bootstrap/), then you could use [bootstrap alerts css styles](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/alerts/), or include bootstrap css in your theme but this option would effect other elements in your site design.

Example from docs similar to the screenshot in your question:

```
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
  <strong>Heads up!</strong> This alert needs your attention, but it's not super important.
</div>
```